# Div clickable through the whole width of the page even though the margin is set to less of the distance

Tags: css, html, margin

Ok, so i have a little bit of a weird problem.

I have been working on a little website for a school project and i needed a panel of buttons on the side.
So i made some divs and made them link to my other pages and so on.

But then a weird problem came up. The area where i could click my divs was not confined to the area of the margin, but it went out to the full length of the page's horizontal axis, but not the vertical.

I have tried searching around for some kind of solution to this problem, but can't seem to find any. I have also tried to change the margin of my divs, but nothing seems to work.

This is the HTML code for my div and the link

```
<a href="main.html">
        <div class="MenuTop">
            <p id="MenuTextOn">Forside</p>
        </div>
    </a>
```

And this is the CSS code associated with that div element.

```
.MenuTop {
position: relative;
border-width: 3px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
width: 70px;
height: 60px;
border-radius: 15px 30px;
opacity: 1;
transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom right, gray, #F0F0F0);
margin: 15px;
```

It should be noted that i'm new to this, but understand the basic principles.

Thanks for helping in advance! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put a `div` inside an `a` element, just style the `a` starting with a `display:block` (to have it as a div by default):

Let's also organise better the CSS

```
.MenuTop {
    /* positioning */
    position: relative;

    /* box-model */
    display: block;
    width: 70px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 15px;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;

    /* style */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom right, gray, #F0F0F0);
    border-radius: 15px 30px;
    opacity: 1;

    /* effects */
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

Have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/7063nkfg/

Answer (score 0):

Read about inline and block elements in HTML - http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/

P.S.You don't need to put **DIV** and **P** tags into **A**, this will make your code difficult to read and undestand.

Make it all simplier, with styles:

html:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" class="menu">Text1</a> 
    <a href="#" class="menu">Text2</a> 
    <a href="#" class="menu">Text3</a> 
</div>
```

css:

```
a.menu {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 60px;
    /* other styles */
}
```